# Php mysql <= is not responding

Tags: php, mysql

```
->where(array('op.ent_date>='=>$params['_startdate'],'op.ent_date<='=>$params['_enddate'],'ps.stat'=>'Active'))
```

Example:
`ent_date= 2017-06-17, 2017-06-18`
When I want to display the data of 2017-06-17 it says no data found.
And when I want to display the data from 2017-06-17 to 2017-06-18.. it only shows the data of 2017-06-17. in '<=' part '=' is not working.

Comment: What is the `where` function?